# Positive elements of a $C^*$ (MURPHY, ex 2-2).

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm studying "MURPHY, *$C^*$-Algebras and  Operator Theory*" thoroughly and got stuck in the following exercise:

> **Exercise 2, chapter 2**. Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra.
>   (a) If $a,b$ are positive elements of $A$, show that $\sigma(ab)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\geq 0\right\}$.
>   (b)If $a$ is an invertible element of $A$, show that $a=u|a|$ for a unique unitary $u$ of $A$. Give an example of an element of $B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$ that cannot be written as a product of a unitary times a positive operator.
>   (c)Show that if $a\in Inv(A)$, then $\Vert a\Vert=\Vert a^{-1}\Vert=1$ if and only if $a$ is a unitary.

Item (b) is easy: the only possibility for $u$ is $u=a(a^{-1})(a^*)^{-1}|a|=(a^*)^{-1}|a|$, which is readily verified to be unitary. For the example, let $a$ be any non-invertible isometry in a Hilbert space $H$ (e.g. $a$ is the unilateral shift in $l^2(\mathbb{Z}_+)$). If $a=up$, $u$ unitary and $p$ positive, then $1=a^*a=p^*u^*up=p^2$, so $p=(1)^{1/2}=1$, hence $a=u$, absurd.

Now, I really have no idea how to proceed with items (a) and (c). If $A$ were abelian, both would be trivial (using the Gelfand representation). I believe that in (c) we have to use the representation given in (b). Actually, to use the Gelfand representation in (c), it suffices to show that $a$ is normal, but I don't see how the hipothesis on the norms would imply that.

Comment: You made a mistake with your $u$, it should be $u = a \cdot |a|^{-1}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (a), you have to use that $\sigma(xy)\cup\{0\}=\sigma(yx)\cup\{0\}$ for any two operators $x,y$. Then
$$
\sigma(ab)=\sigma((ab^{1/2})b^{1/2})\subset\sigma(b^{1/2}ab^{1/2})\cup\{0\}\subset\mathbb R^+.
$$
The point is that $b^{1/2}ab^{1/2}$ is positive.

For (c), 
\begin{align} 
\max\sigma(a^*a)&=\|a^*a\|=\|a\|^2=1=\|a^{-1}\|^2\\ &=\|(a^{-1})^*a^{-1}\|=\|(aa^*)^{-1}\|=1/\min\sigma(aa^*)=1/\min\sigma (a^*a).
\end{align}
Thus $a^*a $ is positive  with spectrum $\{1\} $, so $a^*a=1$. Similarly, $aa^*=1$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write $\sigma((ab^{1/2})b^{1/2})\subseteq\sigma(b^{1/2}ab^{1/2})\cup\left\{0\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. I also wrote the last part better (and accurately).

Comment: Dear Martin, I do not know why you suppose $a>0$. I think without positivity of $a$ we can show $a$ is unitary.Please check my argument. $$||a||_{sp}=\sup_{\lambda\in\sigma(a)}|\lambda|\leq ||a||=1$$ Also $$||a^{-1}||_{sp}=\sup_{\lambda\in \sigma(a)}|\lambda^{-1}|\leq ||a^{-1}||=1$$ so $\sigma(a) \subset \Bbb T$, and we can conclude $a$ is unitary.

Comment: That would work if you knew that  $a $ is normal, which a priori you don't.

Comment: But I do not use normality of $a$ in my argument. Do you mean my argument isn't correct?

Comment: Yes you do. For non-normal operators, it is not true in general that $\|a\|=\sup\{|\lambda|:\ \lambda\in\sigma (a)\} $. For example if  $a=\begin {bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end {bmatrix} $ the left-hand-side is $1$, while the right-hand-side is $0$.

Comment: I used $\sup|\lambda|\leq ||a||$ not equality. Where did I use the normality?

Comment: You used it when you said that  $\sigma (a)\subset \mathbb T $ implies that  $a $ is a unitary. Otherwise it is not true: $a=\begin {bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end {bmatrix} $ has its spectrum contained in the unit circle but it is not a unitary.